# DBExpress and mysql last insert id

Tags: c++, mysql, c++builder, dbexpress

There are several posts about how to get last_insert_id from MySQL and related issues. I found this one post related to DBExpress:  [delphi dxExpress MySQL: invalid LAST_INSERT_ID value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729486/delphi-dxexpress-mysql-invalid-last-insert-id-value)

However, following that post don't help me using the following code to insert a note into a notes table.

```
TSQLQuery* tq = new TSQLQuery(NULL);
tq->SQLConnection = atdbDM->SQLConnection1;

stringstream q;
q <<"INSERT INTO note (created_by, note) VALUES ("<<1234<<", \'<none>\');";
q << "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS lastNoteID;";
tq->SQL->Add(q.str().c_str());
tq->Open();
int noteID = tq->FieldByName("lastNoteID")->AsInteger;
tq->Close();
```

When Open() executes, I get an exception:

```
'You have an error in your SQL syntax; Check the manual that correposnds to   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID... at line1'
```

If I execute the insert statement first, and the SELECT statement individually, I get no error, but the returned ID is always 0.
Anyone knowing what needs to be changed? I am using C++ Builder XE3

Comment: The LAST_INSERT_ID() is the last inserted ID that was successfully inserted.  If your record is not inserted or updated, this value won't be changed.  Many discussions on the MySQL site.  I'm locating the record by the data fields, then loading the ID field, not trusting the LAST_INSERT_ID().

Comment: The problem here is not the LAST_INSERT_ID() per se. Problem seem to be the combination of DBExpress and MySQL ending up saying that the above query is invalid. Getting 0 for the id seem often to be associated with separate queries belonging to two different sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that to prevent multiple sessions to be created, causing last_insertid function to always return 0, one can set the connections AUTOCLONE parameter to false. Then the last insert id function works fine. I.e:

```
MySQLConnection->Connected = true;
MySQLConnection->AutoClone = false; //<- makes last_insert_id work as expected!
```